# How to insert a parameter in the SQL query?

Tags: javascript, sql, database, azure, node-red

I'm creating a hangout bot using nodered.I have a SQL database on Azure and for each user I have an id saved in `msg.conversationId` and I would like to pass this id to a query.
I create a function "sql query" with this query:

```
msg.payload = {action: "Q", query: `SELECT a = ISNULL(Nome, null) FROM Users WHERE id_conversation=${msg.conversationId};`};
```

But, of course I am wrong

This is the node red flow:

[image: Nodered flow]

Does anyone has any suggestions? Thanks so much!

Comment: Please update the question to say which sql node you are using. Without knowing that, we cannot advise what the proper message format is needed.

Comment: ok thank you! The node is Azure SQL

Answer (score 0, accepted):

To debug your script insert

```
node.error(msg.payload);
```

after your msg.payload definition to output the data in the debug tab.

Try to concate the string like

```
msg.payload = {action: "Q", query: "SELECT a = ISNULL(Nome, null) FROM Users WHERE id_conversation=" + msg.conversationId + ";"};
```

alternative:

```
var query = "SELECT a = ISNULL(Nome, null) FROM Users WHERE id_conversation=" + msg.conversationId + ";";
msg.payload = {action: "Q", query: query};
```